# Next js dynamic route issue

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js

I am currently learning next and I am confused as to how to implement dynamic routing.
Here is what I am doing:
[image]
[image: Error]

```
"use client"
import React from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const ID = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return <div>{router.query.id}</div>;
};

export default ID;
```

Some [resources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wm5gMKuwSYk)  claim that the dynamic route,name [], should be in the name of the folder. Other, like the documentation, claim it should be the file. How to make dynamic routes work in Next.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for dynamic routes in nextjs, the parent folder is in brackets while there is a page.tsx in the folder. As you are using nextjs 13. Previous versions of Nextjs dynamic routes could be handled with your routing.

Solution:`check/[id]/page.tsx`., the parent folder is in brackets while there is a page in the folder

Answer (score 1):

Create one more folder in your check folder `[id]` and then create page.tsx inside of the folder and add the following code:

```
"use client"
import React from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const ID = ({params}) => {
  const {id} = params;

  return <div{id}</div>;
};

export default ID;
```